# Superspace derivation of supersymmetric non-linear sigma model in Supersolutions by Deligne and Freed

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, physics, supersymmetry, supermanifolds

I am having a little trouble understanding passage from the linear to the non-linear sigma model in Section 4.1 of [Supersolutions by Deligne and Freed.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9901094.pdf) Most of my confusion comes down to the difference between $D_a D_b$ and $D^2$ which appear in the linear sigma model and the covariantizations $\mathcal{D}_a D_b$ and $\mathcal{D}^2$ which appear in the non-linear sigma model.

First recall the coordinate system $y^{a b}$ and $\theta^a$ on super-Minkowski space $M^{3|2}$ from section 2.3. These can be used to define left invariant odd vector fields $D_a = \partial_a + \theta^b \partial_{a b}$ satisfying $[D_a, D_b] = -2\partial_{a b}$. We will also be interested in the differential operator $D^2 = \epsilon^{a b} D_a D_b$ where $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita symbol.

Let $X$ be a Riemannian manifold equipped with the Levi-Civita connection and consider a superfield $\Phi: M^{3|2} \to X$. On p54 Deligne and Freed use the notation $\mathcal{D}_a$ and $\nabla_{ab}$ for the covariantizations of $D_a$ and $\partial_{ab}$ acting on various bundles on $M^{3|2}$ constructed from the tangent bundle $TX$. I am confused about the properties of $\mathcal{D}_a D_b \Phi$. which I believe is the $(D_a, D_b)$ component of the covariant Hessian of $\Phi$.

- For even vector fields the covariant Hessian is symmetric and equation (4.8) claims that $\mathcal{D}_a D_b = \mathcal{D}_b D_a$. Why didn't the fact that $D_a$ and $D_b$ are odd lead to a minus sign? Why doesn't symmetry cause $0 = \mathcal{D}^2 \Phi = \epsilon^{a b} \mathcal{D}_a \mathcal{D}_b \Phi$
- What is the formula for $\mathcal{D}_a D_b$ when $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual Euclidean metric. It can't be $D_a D_b \Phi$ since equation (2.42) states that $D_a D_b = -(\partial_{a b} - \epsilon_{a b} D^2)$ which is not symmetric in $a$ and $b$. I would expect something like the formula $$D_a (D_b \Phi) - (\nabla_a D_b) \Phi$$ for the ordinary covariant Hessian. Here I have used $\nabla_a$ for the covariant derivative on $M^{3|2}$ with respect to $D_a$.

Are there any other resources which this differential geometry in a mathematical way?